# How to remove gap shown by UIStackView with hidden subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

[image]

In the following image, text which reads `=Search=` is a `UILabel` which is inside a `UIStackView` with background color gray. How can I eliminate the gap at the top of that bar.

Here is how the constraints look like respectively for the above screen outputs:

[image]

Two questions here:

1. Without setting 5 points distance from top layout guide, the stack view is not displayed. how can this be resolved by using 0 to top layout guide?
2. Even with using 5 points to top layout guide, why is the gap showing on top of stack view? How can this gap be eliminated?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and upvoted. Thank you.

updating constraints for the `UILabel` inside the `UIStackView`:
[image]

Comment: This is a bit confusing... Is the `=Search=` label the only object in the Stack View? If so, why embed it in a Stack View? If not, what other objects are in there? And, is the picture on the left how it looks when `=Search=` label is *hidden*? And, does it look correct in IB at design time, but you get this weird layout at runtime?

Comment: @DonMag yes, `=Search=` is the only object in the stack view. There is a condition where it is hidden and shown based on some boolean flag. The image on left, is when stackView to TopLayout constraint is 5 pts. It looks correct in IB at design time.

Comment: OK - curious why you don't simply use a `UILabel` without the Stack View wrapper?

Comment: And... are you saying the *Stack View* has a background color of gray? And that is what you are seeing when the label is hidden?

Comment: Ah - never mind the question about *why use the Stack View wrapper* ... makes it easier than setting a height constraint. In a quick test, though, I'm not seeing the 5-pt gap you're seeing. Maybe start over with a fresh UIViewController (doesn't look like a lot to re-layout)?

Comment: Not using a `UILabel` since if it is hidden, that space cannot be reclaimed. Stack view doest not have a background color. However, the view which is being loaded onto it does have a background color of gray. when label is hidden, that color is not to be seen.

Comment: @DonMag I tried it twice and I'm still seeing gap on both occasions. Are there any insets you are explicitly setting?

Comment: Nope, not setting anything other than position constraints. What are you doing to give your label the padding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156596/discussion-between-donmag-and-as-diu).

Comment: Use the UI debugger to figure out exactly what's causing that gap and what the constraints are.